# How to check if VecDeque contains an element?

Tags: rust, deque

Having a `VecDeque` `deq` and an `item`, how can I find out if `deq` contains `item`? I can do it with an iterator:

```
deq.iter().find(|e| e == item).is_none()
```

But this is a lot of code. I just want to say `deq.contains(item)`, but `VecDeque` has no such method (**edit**: not true anymore, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39781581/2408867)). Any alternatives?

Comment: I'd assume that `Vec` and `VecDeque` don't expose this method because it will always have to be an `O(n)` operation for these data structures. Maybe a different data structure would be more appropriate for your case?

Comment: @Shepmaster in fact, `Vec` does expose `contains()` through its deref to a slice: [here](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.contains).

Comment: @VladimirMatveev that's what I get for assuming!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [Rust 1.12](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2016/09/29/Rust-1.12.html) a **`contains` method** was stabilized for [`LinkedList`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/linked_list/struct.LinkedList.html#method.contains) and [`VecDeque`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/vec_deque/struct.VecDeque.html#method.contains). Therefore the correct answer now is the obvious one:

```
deq.contains(item)
```

Answer (score 4):

The simpler way would probably be

```
deq.iter().any(|e| e == item)
```

but there seems to be no easier way.

Comment: You could create a `Contains` extension trait and implement it for `VecDeque` (and other collections?) using this code. Then you get the shorter code, but still being aware of the algorithmic issues.

Answer (score 3):

As Vladimir Matveev pointed out to me in comments, a slice has a `contains` method, so you could also use that on the inner slices:

```
let (a, b) = deq.as_slices();
a.contains(item) || b.contains(item)
```

As I mentioned in another comment, you can make a trait to give you the nice interface:

```
trait Contains<T> {
    fn contains(&self, item: &T) -> bool;
}

impl<T> Contains<T> for VecDeque<T>
    where T: PartialEq
{
    fn contains(&self, item: &T) -> bool {
        let (a, b) = self.as_slices();
        a.contains(item) || b.contains(item)
    }
}
```